# Standard unix tool for unique set

Tags: python, unix

The following python script prints the first occurrence of a line in a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

x = set() 

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line not in x:
        print line,
        x.add(line)
```

`uniq` only works for adjacent lines. The file this will be used on is very large so `sort | uniq` is not ideal. Is there a standard tool that does this?

Comment: What's your question? If you want comments about your code, you're looking for [codereview.se.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My pardon, I had remembered to mention the standard unix tool in the title but not the body.

Comment: See [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `sort -u`? At least that's what the [uniq man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/uniq.1.html) suggests.

Comment: Thanks, my version of the uniq man page did not mention that.

Answer (score 1):

#### using `awk`

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file.old > file.new
```